# How to decide anode and cathode form electrochemical series?

Tags: electrochemistry

To calculate cell potential one must know that from given half reactions which metal is to be anode and which is cathode.

So from standard reduction potential in electro-chemical series how to find this ?

If one element(say A) is above another element(say B) in the series then which is cathode A or B ?

Comment: Tables are not always given the same way round, so remember that fluorine is most oxidising (positive) and lithium most reducing (negative)

Answer (score 2):

If one element A is above B in the standard electrode potential series, then the one with greater oxidising power or reducing agent(ie,B) is anode. While the one with greater reducing power or oxidising agent (ie, A) is cathode.

[Standard Reduction Potential Table](http://highered.mheducation.com/olcweb/cgi/pluginpop.cgi?it=jpg::::::/sites/dl/free/0023654666/650262/Standard_Reduction_Potential_19_01.jpg::Standard%20reduction%20potentials)

Answer (score 0):

The term 'cathode' is the name given to the electrode which is accepting electrons (ie: undergoing reduction). A given electrode may change from anode to cathode, for example, in a secondary (rechargeable) battery, depending whether it is being 'charged' or 'discharged'.